# some set-face-attribute not being applied when I create a new frame using C-x 5 2

Tags: faces, themes

I've a few `set-face-attribute` statements inside `eval-after-load` blocks inside my zenburn theme configuration. These are working fine when I startup emacs using emacsclient. But, when I create a new frame using `C-x 5 2`, the statements inside `eval-after-load` are not applied for the new frame.

My [theme config](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-zenburn.el) for reference. As a workaround, I create new frames using emacsclient command on the terminal. But I'd not like to do this. Is there any way I fix this problem?

Install `zenburn-theme` and `golden-ratio-scroll-screen` and open `emacs -Q` and run the below steps to reproduce the problem:

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'zenburn-theme)
(require 'golden-ratio-scroll-screen)
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(set-face-attribute 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil
                         :background nil :foreground nil)
```

Now open any file, and run `golden-ratio-scroll-screen-up` or `golden-ratio-scroll-screen-down` and observe the face of the current line as it moves up/down. Now enter `C-x 5 2` to create a new frame and run `golden-ratio-scroll-screen-up` and now you can see that the face settings you applied previously are gone and it has reverted back to its default face settings.

My emacs environment:

```
Emacs version: GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0, NS appkit-1561.40 Version 10.13.5 (Build 17F77))
 of 2018-06-21, built using commit 5583e6460c38c5d613e732934b066421349a5259.

./configure options:
  --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules --enable-locallisppath=/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp --infodir=/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-5583e64_1/share/info/emacs --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-5583e64_1 --with-gnutls --without-x --with-xml2 --with-dbus --with-imagemagick --with-modules --with-rsvg --without-pop --with-ns --disable-ns-self-contained

Features:
  RSVG IMAGEMAGICK DBUS NOTIFY ACL GNUTLS LIBXML2 ZLIB TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS NS MODULES THREADS
```

Comment: Can you please provide a simple, step-by-step recipe to repro the behavior, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Comment: Your link to your code is a 404, but in any case please do as Drew requests and include the code which reproduces the problem in the question text.

Comment: @Drew Added steps to reproduce the problem and fixed the link to my zenburn config.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, still. But yes, if a library has already been loaded into your Emacs session then no, it will not be reloaded by `eval-after-load`. Are you expecting that it will be reloaded? Your code comment speaks of a bug, but I don't see what bug you mean. If you think you've found a bug, please report it, with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess. Now I don't know why set-face-attributes wouldn't work across all frames, but try:

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
     'zenburn
     '(face-settings ((t (:inherit 'default)))))
```

This is assuming zenburn is the official name of the theme (1). What this does is explicitly tells emacs that these settings are part of the zenburn's theme. If that doesn't work I suggest you follow Drew's suggestion and try to create a step-by-step recreation of loading the theme adding the bit of code and seeing if it recreates the problem. By the way your github returns a 404 for me.

1. You can find the official name by just doing M-x load-theme and let tab or auto complete show you the available themes.

Edit: Using your example I can repeat the problem. However if I do:

```
(package-initialize)
(require 'zenburn-theme)
(require 'golden-ratio-scroll-screen)
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'zenburn
 '(golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face
   ((t ((:background nil :foreground nil))))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'golden-ratio-scroll-screen-up)
```

It does not show a little highlight thing when you scroll down/make a new frame. I believe this should work with your current defun setup. I'm not sure why it doesn't (your init.el looks really nice and organized by the way), either way let me know at least if your results in a new emacs -Q matches mine. Switching themes is such a pain...

Edit: From the comments below:

```
 (set-face-foreground 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil) 
 (set-face-background 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil)
```

And [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-20-2.5/html_node/elisp_631.html) are the rest of the functions in case you want to change other faces with different attributes. Reading the source of that function I believe the main problem was the nil funny enough, changing your original answer to

```
 (set-face-attribute 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil
                     :background 'unspecified :foreground 'unspecified)
```

Works as well.

Comment: Yes, `zenburn` is the official name of the theme. I fixed the github link, please check now. I've added steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd tried custom-theme-set-faces for zenburn before setting with `set-face-attribute`. I think the problem with `custom-theme-set-faces` is that we can only change the faces which are present in zenburn theme config and other face changes will not be applied.

Comment: @Chakravarthy Raghunandan edited my answer let me know if it helps.

Comment: Using `custom-theme-set-faces` is not making any difference for golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face, when running emacs normally or in emacsclient

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but does
`(set-face-foreground 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil)`
`(set-face-background 'golden-ratio-scroll-highlight-line-face nil)`
Work?

Comment: that actually fixed my issue. Though I've to add it in `with-eval-after-load` blocks. Can you please edit your answer to include the solution.

Comment: Sure, glad it worked out for you :).

Comment: @Gareth why would using nil not work while using unspecified worked for setting faces across all frames? Emacs themes are confusing

Comment: Yeah no clue, and I share a similar frustration with themes. It's one of the most hair pulling things I've debugged in emacs (when I was trying to setup something where I can switch between two themes on the fly, the catch being I had custom settings for both). Honestly in this case it's probably a bug, as nil should have the same behavior.